# Confusion with dynamic memory allocation to command line arguments in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the output, how can the second string start from the 30th memory address when the first string ends there? I have the same confusion about the 4th string too.

```
// test.c


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%p, %lu\n", &argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
manusoman$ gcc -o k test.c 
manusoman$ ./k a abc d
0x7ffeee21ca28, 3
0x7ffeee21ca30, 1
0x7ffeee21ca38, 3
0x7ffeee21ca40, 1
```

Comment: You’re printing the address of the pointer, not the pointer itself. Change `&argv[i]` to `argv[i]`.

Comment: 1) Addresses are shown in base 16, that's no "30th", it's 0x30. 0x30-0x28 = 8. 2) This is because those are pointers to strings, and you're printing their addresses (a pointer in a 64bit machine is 8 bytes long).

Comment: Oops! Guys, you're right. Thank you. It's a silly mistake. Pointers always get me, no matter how harder I try.

Answer (score 1):

You have two musindersandings here:

1. Hexadecimal numbers
2. Addresses vs pointers

Your first misunderstanding is the meaning of hexadecimal values: If you were right and the values you print were indeed string addresses, the first string would occupy the addresses `28`, `29`, `2a` and `2b` for the string terminating null byte. `2c`, `2d`, `2e` and `2f` would be unallocated, and `30` would be the first byte of the next string.

In other words, in hexadecimal, the `9` is followed by `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` and only then comes the `10`.

Your second misunderstanding is the values you are printing.

```
printf("%p, %lu\n", &argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
```

prints the location inside the array. If you want to print the address of the string itself, you should omit the `&`:

```
printf("%p, %lu\n", argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
```

Comment: Hi @glglgl , I got it. It's such a silly mistake :D